# Rearrange HTML content using XSLT

Tags: xslt

I need to rearrange HTML content using XSLT but I'm having trouble figuring out how.

First I need to add this new li:

```
<li class="ktp-question-set-meta">
                <section property="ktp:metadata" class="ktp-meta">
                    <span property="atom:content-item-name" class="ktp-meta" data-value="lsac810323"></span>
                </section>
                <section property="ktp:tags" class="ktp-meta">
                    <span class="ktp-meta" property="ktp:questionSetType">shared-stimulus</span>
                </section>
            </li>
```

The `data-value="lsac810323` needs to be pulled from the `<section class="ktp-question-meta">` in the the original HTML.

2. The Stimulus section needs to be moved up and changed from `<section>` to an `<li>`
3. the original `<section class="ktp-question-meta">` need to show but the data value need to change from `data-value="lsac810323"` to `data-value="lsac810323.01"`

After that the `<section class="ktp-question-stem">`, `<ol class="ktp-answer-set">`, and `<section property="ktp:explanation" typeof="ktp:Explanation" class="ktp-explanation">` remains the same.

This is my original HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" designation="" enumeration="">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" title="default" href="../../assets/css/main.css" />
        <title>lsac820401</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ol class="ktp-question-set">
            <li typeof="ktp:Question" property="ktp:question" class="ktp-question">
                
                <section class="ktp-question-meta">
                    <section property="ktp:metadata" class="ktp-meta"><span property="atom:content-item-name" class="ktp-meta" data-value="lsac820401"></span></section>
                    <section property="ktp:tags" class="ktp-meta">
                        <span property="ktp:interactionType" class="ktp-meta">single-select</span>
                        <span property="ktp:questionType" class="ktp-meta">Point at Issue</span>
                        <span property="ktp:difficulty" class="ktp-meta">★</span>  
                    </section>
                </section>
                
                <section property="ktp:stimulus" typeof="ktp:Stimulus" class="ktp-stimulus">   
                    <p>stimulus content</p>    
                </section>
                
                <section class="ktp-question-stem">  
                    <p>stem content</p>   
                </section>
                
                <ol class="ktp-answer-set">   
                    <li property="ktp:answer" typeof="ktp:Answer">Answer Choice 1</li>
                    <li property="ktp:answer" typeof="ktp:AnswerCorrect">Answer Choice 2</li>
                    <li property="ktp:answer" typeof="ktp:Answer">Answer Choice 3</li>
                    <li property="ktp:answer" typeof="ktp:Answer">Answer Choice 4</li>
                    <li property="ktp:answer" typeof="ktp:Answer">Answer Choice 5</li>   
                </ol>
                
                <section property="ktp:explanation" typeof="ktp:Explanation" class="ktp-explanation">
                    <section property="ktp:explanation-section" typeof="ktp:feedback" data-title="Feedback" class="ktp-explanation-section">
                        <p>Explanation content</p>
                    </section>
                </section>  
            </li>
        </ol>
    </body>
</html>
```

And this is the rearranged output I need to get to:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" enumeration="" designation="">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link href="../../assets/css/main.css" title="default" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <title>lsac810323</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ol property="ktp:questionSet" typeof="ktp:QuestionSet" class="ktp-question-set">
            <li class="ktp-question-set-meta">
                <section property="ktp:metadata" class="ktp-meta">
                    <span property="atom:content-item-name" class="ktp-meta" data-value="lsac810323"></span>
                </section>
                <section property="ktp:tags" class="ktp-meta">
                    <span class="ktp-meta" property="ktp:questionSetType">shared-stimulus</span>
                </section>
            </li>
            <li class="ktp-stimulus" typeof="ktp:Stimulus" property="ktp:stimulus">
                <p>stimulus content</p>
                <p class="place-top atom-exclude">Stimulus End: Place content above this line</p>
            </li>
            <li class="ktp-question" typeof="ktp:Question" property="ktp:question">
                <section class="ktp-question-meta">
                    <section property="ktp:metadata" class="ktp-meta">
                        <span property="atom:content-item-name" class="ktp-meta" data-value="lsac810323.01"></span>
                    </section>
                    <section property="ktp:tags" class="ktp-meta">
                        <span class="ktp-meta" property="ktp:interactionType">single-select</span>
                        <span class="ktp-meta" property="ktp:questionType"><span class="glossterm">Flaw</span></span>
                        <span class="ktp-meta" property="ktp:difficulty">Check your online resources.</span>
                    </section>
                </section>
                <section class="ktp-question-stem">
                    <p>stem content</p>
                </section>
                <ol class="ktp-answer-set">
                    <li property="ktp:answer" typeof="ktp:Answer">Answer Choice 1</li>
                    <li property="ktp:answer" typeof="ktp:AnswerCorrect">Answer Choice 2</li>
                    <li property="ktp:answer" typeof="ktp:Answer">Answer Choice 3</li>
                    <li property="ktp:answer" typeof="ktp:Answer">Answer Choice 4</li>
                    <li property="ktp:answer" typeof="ktp:Answer">Answer Choice 5</li>
                </ol>
                <section property="ktp:explanation" typeof="ktp:Explanation" class="ktp-explanation">
                    <section property="ktp:explanation-section" typeof="ktp:feedback" data-title="Feedback" class="ktp-explanation-section">
                        <p>Explanation content</p>
                    </section>
                </section>
            </li>
        </ol>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is the XSLT I have so far. I have the structure pulling in correctly and the original content placed in its correct new location but it's not bringing over the

tags or

tags, etc. Please see the section labeled .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:math="http://exslt.org/math"
    xmlns:xd="http://www.oxygenxml.com/ns/doc/xsl"
    xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:mml="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs math xd xhtml mml"
    version="3.0">
    
    <xsl:output encoding="UTF-8" include-content-type="no" indent="no" method="xhtml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    
    
    <!-- attributes, commments, processing instructions, text: copy as is -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|comment()|processing-instruction()|text()">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <!-- elements: create a new element with the same name, but no namespace -->
    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:param name="content-item-name"/>
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()">
                <xsl:with-param name="content-item-name" select="$content-item-name"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <!-- process root -->
    <xsl:template match="xhtml:html">
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;!DOCTYPE html&gt;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:sequence select="'&#x0a;'"/>
        <html>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <!-- process item, pass content item name variable -->
    <xsl:template match="xhtml:li[@property='ktp:question']">
        <li>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()">
                <xsl:with-param name="content-item-name" select="descendant::xhtml:span[@property='atom:content-item-name']/@data-value"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </li>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <!-- branching point for any interaction type-based updates -->
    <xsl:template match="xhtml:li[@property='ktp:question']">
        <li>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()">
                <xsl:with-param name="interactionType" select="//xhtml:span[@property='ktp:interactionType']"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </li>
    </xsl:template>
    
    
        
    
    
    
    <!-- Change content -->
    <xsl:template match="xhtml:ol[@class='ktp-question-set']">
    
        <xsl:variable name="content-item-name" select="xhtml:span[@property='atom:content-item-name']/@data-value"/>
        <xsl:variable name="feedbackPara"
            select="xhtml:section[@property = 'ktp:stimulus']"/>
            <ol property="ktp:questionSet" typeof="ktp:QuestionSet" class="ktp-question-set">
                <li class="ktp-question-set-meta">
                    <section property="ktp:metadata" class="ktp-meta">
                        <span property="atom:content-item-name" class="ktp-meta" data-value="{$content-item-name}"/>
                    </section>
                    <section property="ktp:tags" class="ktp-meta">
                        <span class="ktp-meta" property="ktp:questionSetType">shared-stimulus</span>
                    </section>
                </li>
                <li class="ktp-stimulus" typeof="ktp:Stimulus" property="ktp:stimulus">  
                    
                        
                        <xsl:apply-templates
                            select="descendant::xhtml:section[@property = 'ktp:stimulus']" mode="key"/>
                    
                    <p class="place-top atom-exclude">Stimulus End: Place content above this line</p>
                </li>
                <li class="ktp-question" typeof="ktp:Question" property="ktp:question">
                    <section class="ktp-question-meta">
                        <xsl:apply-templates
                            select="descendant::xhtml:section[@class = 'ktp-question-meta']" mode="key"/>
                        
                    </section>
                    <section class="ktp-question-stem">
                        <xsl:apply-templates
                            select="descendant::xhtml:section[@class = 'ktp-question-stem']" mode="key"/>
                        
                    </section>
                    <ol class="ktp-answer-set">
                        <xsl:apply-templates
                            select="descendant::xhtml:ol[@class = 'ktp-answer-set']" mode="key"/>
                        
                    </ol>
                    <section property="ktp:explanation" typeof="ktp:Explanation" class="ktp-explanation">
                        <xsl:apply-templates
                            select="descendant::xhtml:section[@property = 'ktp:explanation']" mode="key"/>
                        
                    </section>
                </li>                
            </ol>   
    </xsl:template>
    
    
    
    

    <!-- process mathml -->
    <xsl:template match="mml:*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <!-- generate data-uuid -->
    <xsl:template name="assignID">
        <xsl:param name="partial"/>
        <xsl:param name="count" select="string-length(partial)"/>
        
        <xsl:variable name="character">abcdef0123456789</xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="characterLength" select="string-length($character)"/>
        <xsl:variable name="position" select="floor(math:random() * 16) + 1"/>
        
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$count &lt; 32">
                <xsl:call-template name="assignID">
                    <xsl:with-param name="count" select="$count + 1"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="partial">
                        <xsl:value-of select="$partial"/>
                        <xsl:value-of select="substring($character,$position,1)"/>
                    </xsl:with-param>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$count = 32">
                <xsl:value-of select="$partial"/>
            </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Why don't you post your attempt so we can fix it, instead of having to write your code for you from scratch.

Comment: I added my attempt at the XSLT script but it's not working very well at all as my XSLT knowledge is very limited.

Comment: In case you did not know, usually HTML is not as rules compliant like XML to be usable in XSLT. Fortunately, your posted HTML is well-formed. See [Is HTML5 valid XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5558502/1422451)

Comment: I suggest you reduce your example to the minimum required to demonstrate the problem - and reduce the problem to a single one instead of three.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:math="http://exslt.org/math"
    xmlns:xd="http://www.oxygenxml.com/ns/doc/xsl"
    xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:mml="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs math xd xhtml mml"
    version="3.0">
    
    <xsl:output encoding="UTF-8" include-content-type="no" indent="no" method="xhtml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    
    
    <!-- attributes, commments, processing instructions, text: copy as is -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|comment()|processing-instruction()|text()">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <!-- elements: create a new element with the same name, but no namespace -->
    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:param name="content-item-name"/>
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()">
                <xsl:with-param name="content-item-name" select="$content-item-name"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <!-- process root -->
    <xsl:template match="xhtml:html">
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;!DOCTYPE html&gt;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:sequence select="'&#x0a;'"/>
        <html>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <!-- process item, pass content item name variable -->
    <xsl:template match="xhtml:li[@property='ktp:question']">
        <li>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()">
                <xsl:with-param name="content-item-name" select="descendant::xhtml:span[@property='atom:content-item-name']/@data-value"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </li>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <!-- branching point for any interaction type-based updates -->
    <xsl:template match="xhtml:li[@property='ktp:question']">
        <li>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()">
                <xsl:with-param name="interactionType" select="//xhtml:span[@property='ktp:interactionType']"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </li>
    </xsl:template>
    
    
        
    
    
    
    <!-- Change content -->
    <xsl:template match="xhtml:ol[@class='ktp-question-set']">
    
        <xsl:variable name="content-item-name" select="xhtml:span[@property='atom:content-item-name']/@data-value"/>
        <xsl:variable name="feedbackPara"
            select="xhtml:section[@property = 'ktp:stimulus']"/>
            <ol property="ktp:questionSet" typeof="ktp:QuestionSet" class="ktp-question-set">
                <li class="ktp-question-set-meta">
                    <section property="ktp:metadata" class="ktp-meta">
                        <xsl:apply-templates
                            select="descendant::xhtml:span[@property = 'atom:content-item-name']"/>
                    </section>
                    <section property="ktp:tags" class="ktp-meta">
                        <span class="ktp-meta" property="ktp:questionSetType">shared-stimulus</span>
                    </section>
                </li>
                <li class="ktp-stimulus" typeof="ktp:Stimulus" property="ktp:stimulus">  
                                           
                        <xsl:apply-templates 
                            select="descendant::xhtml:section[@property = 'ktp:stimulus']"/>
                    
                    <p class="place-top atom-exclude">Stimulus End: Place content above this line</p>
                </li>
                <li class="ktp-question" typeof="ktp:Question" property="ktp:question">
                    
                    <section class="ktp-question-meta">
                        <section property="ktp:metadata" class="ktp-meta">   
                    <xsl:apply-templates
                        select="descendant::xhtml:span[@property = 'atom:content-item-name']"/>.01
                        </section>
                        <xsl:apply-templates
                            select="descendant::xhtml:section[@property = 'ktp:tags']"/>
                    </section>   
                                       
                        <xsl:apply-templates
                            select="descendant::xhtml:section[@class = 'ktp-question-stem']"/>
         
                        <xsl:apply-templates
                            select="descendant::xhtml:ol[@class = 'ktp-answer-set']"/>
            
                        <xsl:apply-templates
                            select="descendant::xhtml:section[@property = 'ktp:explanation']"/>
           
                </li>                
            </ol>   
    </xsl:template>
    
    
    
    

    <!-- process mathml -->
    <xsl:template match="mml:*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <!-- generate data-uuid -->
    <xsl:template name="assignID">
        <xsl:param name="partial"/>
        <xsl:param name="count" select="string-length(partial)"/>
        
        <xsl:variable name="character">abcdef0123456789</xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="characterLength" select="string-length($character)"/>
        <xsl:variable name="position" select="floor(math:random() * 16) + 1"/>
        
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$count &lt; 32">
                <xsl:call-template name="assignID">
                    <xsl:with-param name="count" select="$count + 1"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="partial">
                        <xsl:value-of select="$partial"/>
                        <xsl:value-of select="substring($character,$position,1)"/>
                    </xsl:with-param>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$count = 32">
                <xsl:value-of select="$partial"/>
            </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```